# When Angular loads Forms/ngForms are temporarily all $valid

Tags: angularjs

When Angular is bootstrapping or intially digesting forms that are loaded are temporarily $valid even though they have no values, which causes some charts I have to blink whenever those views are loaded.  How/Where would you debounce this, or $watch for initial loading to be complete?